# DataTable.Select.Where VB.Net - Delete rows

Tags: vb.net, datatable, where-clause, delete-row

I'm currently pulling information using a query that I'm not allowed to tamper with:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = BLL.GetData(variable).Tables(0)
```

Immediately afterwards, I'm removing any records where a field begins with a specific value:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    If dr.Item(2).ToString().StartsWith("value") Then
        dr.Delete()
    End If
Next
```

What I'd really like to do is something like:

```
dt.Select.Where(field1 => field1.StartsWith("value")).Delete()
```

I know that is not the syntax of it and I'm probably very off from what it would be like.  The `For Each` works fine, I'm just trying to "simplify" it.  Any idea?  Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, your initial code is probably the cleanest and most straight forward.

To delete items using LINQ, you first need to read them into a separate collection, then loop through that collection and call Delete on each record. If you'd rather go that route, you could try:

```
Dim records = dt.Rows.Where(Function(r) r.StartsWith("value")).ToList()
For Each r In records
    r.Delete()
Next
```

Comment: @user574632 - If you simply wanted a collection with the rows that don't start with "value", then yes. But the OP specifically says they want to delete the rows.

Comment: Hmmm, both ways might work.  This is pre-draw to the screen, so either doing the NOT or deleting them might work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I think you are looking for is below from Microsoft. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Dim table As DataTable = DataSet1.Tables("Orders")

```
' Presuming the DataTable has a column named Date.
Dim expression As String
expression = "Date > #1/1/00#"
Dim foundRows() As DataRow

' Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
foundRows = table.Select(expression)

Dim i As Integer
' Print column 0 of each returned row.
For i = 0 to foundRows.GetUpperBound(0)
   Console.WriteLine(foundRows(i)(0))
Next i
```